# MyBatis - How to transform data before saving to DB table

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis to save data to SQLite database in simple Java application. Is it possible to configure MyBatis to perform data transformation in communication between Java class and DB table?

For example, I have java.util.Date object in my Java class and I want to save it as number (Unix time). Another example: in Java class I have a BigDecimal number which I want to store as text (I don't want to loose any precision).

In Java objects, I use appropriate getters and setters to convert such data, but I don't see any possibilities to specify them in MyBatis .xml files.

To sum up, my questions:
1. Can I use Java getters and setters in MyBatis Result Map? If yes, than how?
2. How to properly store complex data (such as Dates and BigDecimals) in DB via MyBatis?

Comment: Better give some example so we can help u better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get in working by using [TypeHandler](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) class. Here is example code for mapping BigDecimal to TEXT db column:

```
public class BigDecimalTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<BigDecimal> {
    public BigDecimal getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException{
        String str_val = rs.getString(columnIndex);
        BigDecimal res;

        if( str_val == null || str_val.equals("") )
            res = new BigDecimal(0);
        else
            res = new BigDecimal(str_val);

        return res;
    }
    public BigDecimal getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException{
        String str_val = rs.getString(columnName);
        BigDecimal res;

        if( str_val == null || str_val.equals("") )
            res = new BigDecimal(0);
        else
            res = new BigDecimal(str_val);

        return res;
    }
    public BigDecimal getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException{
        String str_val = cs.getString(columnIndex);
        BigDecimal res;

        if( str_val == null || str_val.equals("") )
            res = new BigDecimal(0);
        else
            res = new BigDecimal(str_val);

        return res;
    }
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, BigDecimal parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException{
        if( parameter != null )
            ps.setString(i, parameter.toString());
        else
            ps.setString(i, "0");
    }
}
```

And in MyBatis config file:

```
<configuration>
    (...)
    <typeHandlers>
        <typeHandler javaType="BigDecimal" jdbcType="VARCHAR" handler="example.com.BigDecimalTypeHandler"/>
    </typeHandlers>
    (...)
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the 'bind' element of mybatis could save you the trouble

```
<select id="selectBlogsLike" resultType="Blog">
  <bind name="pattern" value="'%' + _parameter.getTitle() + '%'" />
  SELECT * FROM BLOG
  WHERE title LIKE #{pattern}
</select>
```

In this case, it's using the getter and concatenating %. In your case, you can make simple transformations there.

http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html

Comment: First of all, thank You for the answer. It seems like a good way to handle queries with WHERE, but I'm not sure if it will work for mapping table rows to Java class. I've found TypeHandler class in MyBatis and I think, it is the proper way to achieve my goals. I'll experiment with it and, if I'm successful, I'll post it as an answer here.